# Coverting ROM for MTK 6575

Tags: rom-flashing

My phone was already a dead unit but can still be detected by SPFT (Smart Phone Flash Tool). What I  have is a Stock Flashable Rom which is in zip file. Is there a way to convert this into .md5 or .pmt? Or how can I flash this through SPFT.

And also, while doing the (SPFT) memory test, I got an error saying "NAND Flash not detected on phone" How can I solve this?? Thanks!!

I'm using Alcatel OT 5020a

Answer (score 1):

For MTK devices you should use SP Flash Tool please find a complete Tutorial here http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=1982587 propably this will save you from the currently situation. I am not responsible for anything may happen.

Comment: Thanks! But I do know how to use the Flash Tool, What I dont know is how to fix the NAND Flash, And how to flash a cwm flashable ROM using SPFT. 

But still, thanks you for trying to help..